# Add SOAP header object using pure JAX-WS

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws, paypal, webservice-client

I'm trying to implement simple web service client for *PayPal Express Checkout API* using **JAX WS**. *PayPal Express Checkout API* provides **WSDL** file, from which I was able to generate Java classes using *CXF's wsdl2java* utility.

From authentication reasons, it demands adding **SOAP Header** to each request. This header is quite simple and should look like here:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECSOAPAPIBasics#id09C3I0CF0O6

Generated from **WSDL** classes include **ebay.apis.eblbasecomponents.CustomSecurityHeaderType** class which represents header which I need to add to each request.

So the question is: how can I add manually created instance of **CustomSecurityHeaderType** class to SOAP request's header taking into account following conditions:

1. I'm not very eager to use classes from **com.sun.*** package as mentioned in answer here: [JAX-WS - Adding SOAP Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322953/jax-ws-adding-soap-headers) (mainly because of possible portability issues between different JDK's)
2. I don't want to manually marshal that object into *nested* **javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement** instances as mentioned in answer here:
   [How do I add a SOAP Header using Java JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830691/how-do-i-add-a-soap-header-using-java-jax-ws)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So, it looks like I've found possible answer while combining **JAX-WS** & **JAXB** related answers from *SO* (I would really appreciate if somebody experienced in these technologies can check whether following is correct):

The obvious thing for me is to add SOAP message handler and alter header of **SOAPMessage** instance in it:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Binding;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import ebay.api.paypalapi.ObjectFactory; // class generated by wsdl2java

// following class is generated by wsdl2java utility Service class
final PayPalAPIInterfaceService payPalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceService();
final PayPalAPIAAInterface expressCheckoutPort = payPalService.getPayPalAPIAA();
final Binding binding = ((BindingProvider) expressCheckoutPort).getBinding();
List<Handler> handlersList = new ArrayList<Handler>();

// now, adding instance of Handler to handlersList which should do our job:
// creating header instance
final CustomSecurityHeaderType headerObj = new CustomSecurityHeaderType();
final UserIdPasswordType credentials = new UserIdPasswordType();
credentials.setUsername("username");
credentials.setPassword("password");
credentials.setSignature("signature");
headerObj.setCredentials(credentials);

// bookmark #1 - please read explanation after code
final ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
// creating JAXBElement from headerObj
final JAXBElement<CustomSecurityHeaderType> requesterCredentials = objectFactory.createRequesterCredentials(headerObj);

handlersList.add(new SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(final SOAPMessageContext context) {        
        try {
            // checking whether handled message is outbound one as per Martin Strauss answer
            final Boolean outbound = (Boolean) context.get("javax.xml.ws.handler.message.outbound");
            if (outbound != null && outbound) {
                // obtaining marshaller which should marshal instance to xml
                final Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomSecurityHeaderType.class).createMarshaller();
                // adding header because otherwise it's null
                final SOAPHeader soapHeader = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().addHeader();
                // marshalling instance (appending) to SOAP header's xml node
                marshaller.marshal(requesterCredentials, soapHeader);
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return true;
    }

    // ... default implementations of other methods go here

});

// as per Jean-Bernard Pellerin's comment setting handlerChain list here, after all handlers were added to list
binding.setHandlerChain(handlersList);
```

Explanation of *bookmark #1*:
one should marshal not the header object itself, but **JAXBElement** representing that object, because otherwise one will get an exception. One should use one of **ObjectFactory** classes which are generated from **WSDL** for creating needed **JAXBElement** instances from original objects.
(Thanks @skaffman for answer: [No @XmlRootElement generated by JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819720/no-xmlrootelement-generated-by-jaxb) )

### One should also refer to `Martin Straus` answer which extends this one

Comment: Managed to invoke PayPal API's web service method and obtain successful response, hence accepting this answer.

Comment: I think you should include Martin Straus's outbound check as well to your code.

Comment: From user: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2425676/kai-witte I believe the list of handlers must be created and filled first, THEN set as the handler chain. SOAPHandlers that are added after calling sethandlerChain won't register.

Comment: So you have not managed to find any other way than just using the MessageHandler to set SOAPHeaders? Do you know the reason why this cannot be done the same was a by using com.sun.* packages?

Comment: I think this can be done using classes from `com.sun.*` packages. The only problem with them is that these classes will be present only in Sun's (Oracle) JVM and not present in other JVM implementations, so code which uses `com.sun.*` packages will not run on other JVMs.

Comment: Hey @Yuva I am also facing same issue here for paypal. I have also creatd soap client using wsdl, and trying to add request header as shown in your answer, but not getting some files. This is my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185802/use-paypal-with-java

Comment: Please let me know if you can guide me ? ObjectFactory is not created in my web service client, I have used simple web service client option in eclipse.Also tried wsdl to java(axis generator) but getting some fileNotFound excpetion.

Comment: thank you a lot, this solution saved me a lot of time.

does anyone know why the header is not automatically generated?

Comment: @eeezyy I'm glad that it helped you! And I don't have the slightest idea why header is not automatically generated :)

Answer (score 11):

This solution works great, but there's a catch. It generates this error when the inbound message is processed:

```
dic 19, 2012 7:00:55 PM com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl addHeader
SEVERE: SAAJ0120: no se puede agregar una cabecera si ya hay una
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Can't add a header when one is already present.
    at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientSOAPHandlerTube.callHandlersOnResponse(ClientSOAPHandlerTube.java:167)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerTube.processResponse(HandlerTube.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1074)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:979)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:950)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:825)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:443)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
    at $Proxy38.wsRdyCrearTicketDA(Unknown Source)
    at ar.com.fit.fides.remedy.api.ws.ServicioCreacionTickets.crearTicket(ServicioCreacionTickets.java:55)
    at ar.com.fit.fides.remedy.api.ws.ConectorRemedyWS.crearTicket(ConectorRemedyWS.java:43)
    at ar.com.fit.fides.remedy.api.ws.ConectorRemedyWS.main(ConectorRemedyWS.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Can't add a header when one is already present.
    at ar.com.fit.fides.remedy.api.ws.AuthenticationHandler.handleMessage(AuthenticationHandler.java:50)
    at ar.com.fit.fides.remedy.api.ws.AuthenticationHandler.handleMessage(AuthenticationHandler.java:23)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor.callHandleMessageReverse(HandlerProcessor.java:341)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor.callHandlersResponse(HandlerProcessor.java:214)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientSOAPHandlerTube.callHandlersOnResponse(ClientSOAPHandlerTube.java:161)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Can't add a header when one is already present.
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.addHeader(EnvelopeImpl.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.addHeader(EnvelopeImpl.java:108)
    at ar.com.fit.fides.remedy.api.ws.AuthenticationHandler.handleMessage(AuthenticationHandler.java:45)
```

So, the solution is to check whether the message being handled if the outbound message, like this:

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    try {
        Boolean outbound = (Boolean) context.get("javax.xml.ws.handler.message.outbound");
        if (outbound != null && outbound) {
            // obtaining marshaller which should marshal instance to xml
            final Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(AuthenticationInfo.class).createMarshaller();
            // adding header because otherwise it's null
            final SOAPHeader soapHeader = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().addHeader();
            // marshalling instance (appending) to SOAP header's xml node
            marshaller.marshal(info, soapHeader);
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hello Martin, I am new in web services, please give me a hint what is inbound and outbound messages ?

Comment: Hello Martin, Following is my problem when i try to add jaxb element in SOAP header. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320675/eway-payment-gateway-add-headers-using-soap-service-in-recuring-payment-using-j

Answer (score 5):

I created a web service exposing method with params user and password as header like this:

```
@WebService(serviceName="authentication")
public class WSAuthentication {
   String name = null;
   String password = null;

   public WSAuthentication() {
       super();
   }

   public WSAuthentication(String name, String password) {
       this.name = name;
       this.password = password;
   }

   private static String getData(WSAuthentication sec) {
       System.out.println("********************* AUTHENTICATION ********************" + "\n" + 
       "**********USER: " + sec.name + "\n" + 
       "******PASSWORD: " + sec.password + "\n" + 
       "******************************** AUTHENTICATION ****************************");
       return sec.name + " -- " + sec.password;
   }

   @WebMethod(operationName="security", action="authenticate")
   @WebResult(name="answer")
   public String security(@WebParam(header=true, mode=Mode.IN, name="user") String user, @WebParam(header=true, mode=Mode.IN, name="password") String password) {
        WSAuthentication secure = new WSAuthentication(user, password);
        return getData(secure);
     }
}
```

Try compiling it and testing generated from WSDL class. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I will check how my solution works with your sample web service implementation and report back here.

Comment: Concerning WSAuthentication class - I've managed to create and run web service out of it, and send requests to it. However, I ran into the problem similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380761/soap-header-using-jax-wsserver-side and could solve it. Nevertheless, it was nice experience, thus +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer:

[JAX-WS - Adding SOAP Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322953/jax-ws-adding-soap-headers)

Basically you add -XadditionalHeaders to the compiler options and objects in the headers also appear in your generated code as parameters of the method.

Comment: That's interesting approach and it looks quite graceful, however I'm failing to understand how to do this exactly in this case, could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven, and the jaxws-maven-plugin all you have to do is add the xadditionalHeaders flag to true and the client will be generated with the methods that have the headers as input.

https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html#xadditionalHeaders