# REST to SOAP Headers

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

I have a SOAP web service developed with JAX-WS that looks like this:

```
@WebService(...)
public class SOAP_Service implements JAXWS_Interface {
    public SOAP_Service() {
        JaxWsServerFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();

        List<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<Handler>();
        handlers.add(new SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>() {
            // Read SOAP headers
        });

        factory.addHandlers(handlers);
    }

    @Override
    public FooResponse foo(FooRequest req) {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

The SoapHandler is the best strategy I've come up with for reading the headers of an incoming SOAP request envelope ([Add SOAP header object using pure JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654608/add-soap-header-object-using-pure-jax-ws)). I've not been able to discover a way to use header data in the `foo` call.

I also have a REST web service developed with RESTEasy that looks like this:

```
@Path("")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class REST_Service {
    JAXWS_Service service = new JAXWS_Service();
    JAXWS_Interface interface = service.getJAXWS_Interface();

    public REST_Service() {
        final List<Handler> handlerList = new ArrayList<Handler>();
        handlerList.add(new SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
            // Inject SOAP headers
        });
    }

    @GET
    @PATH("/foo")
    public FooResponse foo(
        @HeaderParam("bar") String bar,
        @QueryParam("fooParam1") String fooParam1)
    {
        FooRequest request = new FooRequest();
        request.setFooParam1(fooParam1);

        interface.foo(request);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is placing REST header parameters into SOAP headers. I've thought of two solutions but I don't like either

1. In `foo`, create a new instance of `JAXWS_SERVICE`, `JAXWS_INTERFACE`, and passing `final bar` into the inner `SOAPHandler`.

   - I don't like this because it requires recreating our SOAP service + handlers every request, which I'd imagine is very inefficient.
2. In `foo`, set a variable in an implementation of `SOAPHandler` which will be injected into the SOAP Header when `handleMessage()` is called.

   - I actually think this won't work due to a lack of synchronisation.

I've been thinking, reading, and researching and I could use some advice or a better solution to my problem.

Comment: JAX-WS and JAX-RS are different specifications. They don't mix. What do you want to do? Is your question about extracting HTTP headers from a SOAP call?

Comment: Close, I'm not looking to extract incoming SOAP headers, but rather programmatically insert headers into an outgoing SOAP header, per REST call. I suppose REST isn't the important detail, I'd like to be able to do it with any web service client. It just so happens this client is also a REST endpoint...