# Use paypal with java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, paypal, jax-ws

I want to use paypal as a payment process in my application.

At paypal they have shown many ways as using REST API, classic api, and also using SOAP API.

I am trying to use SOAP client by following way.

1.I am trying to create a SOAP web service client using paypal's provided wsdl file. But it's giving me error while creating client as ' unable to retieve that url',though it creates client files.

2.Created object for proxyClass, as proxy class contains all required methods like getAuthDetails,setExpressCheckout,setEndPoint etc.

3.So these method contains parameters like DetailLevelCodeType[]detailLevel,MessageElement[]_any. so what will be the value for it ?

4.As per my understanding if I am performing any operation on payapal, it should ask me first authentication parameters like username,secret, token, password of my account.
When it comes to paypal using rest api, I am aware about getting access token by providing user credentials.

```
So in soap web service client how to get that first? I didin't get any method available here for that.
```

But I have got one way to perform authorization from this link. [security credentials](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/PayPalSOAPAPIArchitecture/) .

So I followed these steps, now I have my username,password.

> In next topic they are explaining , your SOAP client must set the
>   Username, Password elements to pass an API username/password
>   combination in the SOAP request header.

So I am trying in this way to add username,password in request header [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654608/add-soap-header-object-using-pure-jax-ws).

This process includes marshalling.

//packages used so far

```
import javax.xml.ws.Binding;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        PayPalAPIAAInterfaceProxy proxy=new PayPalAPIAAInterfaceProxy();

    //  proxy.setEndpoint("");

        // following class is generated by wsdl2java utility Service class
        final PayPalAPIInterfaceService payPalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceLocator();
        PayPalAPIAAInterface expressCheckoutPort;
        try {
            expressCheckoutPort = payPalService.getPayPalAPIAA();
            final Binding binding = ((BindingProvider) expressCheckoutPort).getBinding();
            List<Handler> handlersList = new ArrayList<Handler>();

            // now, adding instance of Handler to handlersList which should do our job:
            // creating header instance
            final CustomSecurityHeaderType headerObj = new CustomSecurityHeaderType();
            final UserIdPasswordType credentials = new UserIdPasswordType();
            credentials.setUsername("username");
            credentials.setPassword("password");
            credentials.setSignature("signature");
            headerObj.setCredentials(credentials);


            // bookmark #1 - please read explanation after code
            final ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
            // creating JAXBElement from headerObj
            final JAXBElement<CustomSecurityHeaderType> requesterCredentials = objectFactory.createRequesterCredentials(headerObj);

            handlersList.add(new SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>() {
                @Override
                public boolean handleMessage(final SOAPMessageContext context) {        
                    try {
                        // checking whether handled message is outbound one as per Martin Strauss answer
                        final Boolean outbound = (Boolean) context.get("javax.xml.ws.handler.message.outbound");
                        if (outbound != null && outbound) {
                            // obtaining marshaller which should marshal instance to xml
                            final Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomSecurityHeaderType.class).createMarshaller();
                            // adding header because otherwise it's null
                            final SOAPHeader soapHeader = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().addHeader();
                            // marshalling instance (appending) to SOAP header's xml node
                            marshaller.marshal(requesterCredentials, soapHeader);
                        }
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                // ... default implementations of other methods go here

            });

            // as per Jean-Bernard Pellerin's comment setting handlerChain list here, after all handlers were added to list
            binding.setHandlerChain(handlersList);


        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }
```

But I observed a file is missing named `ObjectFactory` .

> I have included Merchant api sdk's jar file also. And in my web service
>   client this file is not present.
>
> So can anybody guide me in this context that why file is not getting
>   created when creating client from wsdl file ?

I have also tried to create web service client using wsdl to java plugin, but it is giving me error as

> wsdlexception faultcode other_error ,it's also saying
>   FileNotFoundException

, unable to find `https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl/eBLBaseComponents.xsd`

Comment: My suggestion is best way is through REST API Try this Link:
[https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal) Hope this Helps you

Comment: I have tried with this REST API, the sample code given here works, that's good, but I want to perform one time payment process and then concurrent billing(I think it will be done using billing agreement) . So does rest api contains all these supported methods?

Comment: Yes absolutely...!! it contains almost all required supported methods @Java

Comment: Has anybody used paypal with only using web service SOAP client? As I observed I am getting this error because of jar files conflicts. Number of files like `SetExpressCheckoutResponseType`,`SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType` and many more exist in `payment-base.jar` and in client created using soap (from wsdl).

Comment: So can anybody used paypal using only SOAP web service client i.e generated from provided wsdl files by paypal.?

Comment: Is there anyone who has worked on paypal integration using soap client?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: though I managed to use PayPal web services API around 2 years ago, it was kind of cumbersome to do, so I'll advise you to use `REST API`, since it looks like PayPal fails to keep web service API consistent.

However, I'll try to give you hints on how to use web service API from PayPal:
It seems you are doing everything right, the problem is in `PayPalSvc.wsdl` file, because it references `eBLBaseComponents.xsd` file which should be located next to `PayPalSvc.wsdl` file. If you navigate to url in browser

> https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/eBLBaseComponents.xsd

you'll see that that file exists at that location.

Same goes for `CoreComponentTypes.xsd` and `EnhancedDataTypes.xsd` files which are also referenced by `PayPalSvc.wsdl` file.

Now, I quickly tried to use `Apache CXFs wsdl2java` utility to generate client classes and it gave me the same error you have. I don't know why those utilities are expecting those `xsd` files to be located in `https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl/` location.

So, what you can do to bypass this problem is to:

1. Download `PayPalSvc.wsdl`, `CoreComponentTypes.xsd`, `eBLBaseComponents.xsd` and `EnhancedDataTypes.xsd` files to your computer
2. Put them all into single folder on your computer
3. Run the utility again pointing to the local `PayPalSvc.wsdl` file
4. If `file not found` error is shown, try to find that file on the web, download it and try again
5. In case of any problems - add comments, I (or somebody else) will try to help

Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks for reply.I have downloded wsdl and xsd to my local.Now I am trying to create web service client using axis generator plugin, but it's  giving me error as `specified WSDL is invalid!, Please select a validated *.wsdl/*.xml file on previous page`. I am providing correct path for wsdl from local .

Comment: Try `Apache CXF wsdl2java` utility command: `wsdl2java -client <path-to>/PayPalSvc.wdsl`

Comment: I tried with `Apache CXF wsdl2java` also , but still giving error for xsd.

Comment: I want to perform concurrent billing process on paypal, so I am trying to use soap client sdk, but I am getting `unable to create soap connection `I am following this blog.`http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/07/17/paypal-express-checkout-with-java/`

Comment: Could you please post full stack trace of exception? I didn't work with PayPal soap client SDK

Comment: please find full stack trace of exception here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285263/unable-to-establish-soap-connection-while-using-paypal-api`

Answer (score 0):

PayPal provides libs for Java which makes the integration a lot easier for you.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/paypal/sdk/

I used merchantsdk and paypal-core for my express-checkout integration.