# Unable to establish SOAP connection while using paypal api

Tags: java, web-services, soap, paypal

I am tryin gto use paypal soap client, and performing setExpressCheckout method with [Paypal Express Checkout with Java](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/07/17/paypal-express-checkout-with-java/) reference.

> So here I am using only paypal-base.jar and paypal-stubs.jar instead
>   of soap client (generated from wsdl).

```
    public class SetExpressCheckoutService{

        private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SetExpressCheckoutService.class);

        public static void main(String[] args){
            SetExpressCheckoutService setExpressCheckoutService = new SetExpressCheckoutService();

            //the parameters for the service
            Long userId = 5l;
            String amount = "25";
            String returnURL = "http://localhost:8080/integratingstuff-paypal/return_after_payment.xhtml";
            String cancelURL = "http://localhost:8080/integratingstuff-paypal/cancel_payment.xhtml";
            PaymentActionCodeType paymentAction = PaymentActionCodeType.Sale;
            CurrencyCodeType currencyCode = CurrencyCodeType.EUR;

            try {
                //calling the service, setting up the checkoutpage
                String token = setExpressCheckoutService.setExpressCheckout(userId, amount, currencyCode, returnURL,cancelURL,paymentAction);
                log.info("Url to redirect to: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=" + token);
            } catch (PayPalException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }

        public String setExpressCheckout(Long userId, String paymentAmount,
                CurrencyCodeType currencyCodeType, String returnURL, String cancelURL,
                    PaymentActionCodeType paymentAction) throws PayPalException{



CallerServices caller = new CallerServices();

            //construct and set the profile, these are the credentials we establish as "the shop" with Paypal
            APIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();
            profile.setAPIUsername("sdk-three_api1.sdk.com");
            profile.setAPIPassword("QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q");
            profile.setSignature("AVGidzoSQiGWu.lGj3z15HLczXaaAcK6imHawrjefqgclVwBe8imgCHZ");
            profile.setEnvironment("sandbox");
            caller.setAPIProfile(profile);

            //construct the request
            SetExpressCheckoutRequestType pprequest = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
            pprequest.setVersion("63.0");

            //construct the details for the request
            SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType details = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();

            PaymentDetailsType paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
            paymentDetails.setOrderDescription("Integrating Stuff Test Order");
            paymentDetails.setInvoiceID("INVOICE-" + Math.random());
            BasicAmountType orderTotal = new BasicAmountType(paymentAmount);
            orderTotal.setCurrencyID(currencyCodeType);
            paymentDetails.setOrderTotal(orderTotal);
            paymentDetails.setPaymentAction(paymentAction);
            details.setPaymentDetails(new PaymentDetailsType[]{paymentDetails});

            details.setReturnURL(returnURL);
            details.setCancelURL(cancelURL);
            details.setCustom(userId.toString());

            //set the details on the request
            pprequest.setSetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails(details);

            //call the actual webservice, passing the constructed request
            SetExpressCheckoutResponseType ppresponse = (SetExpressCheckoutResponseType) caller.call("SetExpressCheckout", pprequest);

            //get the token from the response
            return ppresponse.getToken();
        }
    }
```

I have tried to execute this method, but I am getting exception as
`com.paypal.sdk.exceptions.FatalException: Unable to establish SOAP connection`

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.paypal.sdk.core.APICallerBase.getEndpointUrl(APICallerBase.java:296)

Full stacktrace is :

```
com.paypal.sdk.exceptions.FatalException: Unable to establish SOAP connection
        at com.paypal.sdk.core.soap.SOAPAPICaller.setupConnection(SOAPAPICaller.java:292)
        at com.paypal.sdk.services.CallerServices.setAPIProfile(CallerServices.java:112)
        at com.imedicor.liferay.organizations.util.PaypalService.setExpressCheckout(PaypalService.java:92)
        at com.imedicor.liferay.organizations.util.PaypalService.testing(PaypalService.java:43)
        at org.apache.jsp.organization_005fdetails_jsp._jspService(organization_005fdetails_jsp.java:500)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:323)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:134)
        at com.imedicor.liferay.organizations.portlet.OrganizationPortlet.doView(OrganizationPortlet.java:83)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.doDispatch(LiferayPortlet.java:218)
        at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doDispatch(MVCPortlet.java:319)
        at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
        at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:534)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:607)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:359)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1207)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:97)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:90)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(PACLRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:54)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:5158)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.renderPortlet(PortalUtil.java:1569)
        at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:165)
        at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:203)
        at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:190)
        at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:87)
        at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.velocity.TemplateProcessor.processMax(TemplateProcessor.java:165)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.doInvoke(UberspectImpl.java:389)
        at org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:378)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:270)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:262)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.render(ASTReference.java:342)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:336)
        at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:328)
        at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:235)
        at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:381)
        at com.liferay.portal.velocity.VelocityEngineImpl.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngineImpl.java:264)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.velocity.VelocityEngineUtil.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngineUtil.java:73)
        at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.doProcessTemplate(RuntimePortletImpl.java:499)
        at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.doDispatch(RuntimePortletImpl.java:394)
        at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePortletImpl.java:228)
        at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:125)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.control_005fpanel_jsp._jspService(control_005fpanel_jsp.java:676)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:468)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:735)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:187)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:560)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:537)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:138)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:335)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:294)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:241)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:246)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
        at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:163)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:216)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:187)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.paypal.sdk.core.APICallerBase.getEndpointUrl(APICallerBase.java:296)
        at com.paypal.sdk.core.soap.SOAPAPICaller.setupConnection(SOAPAPICaller.java:193)
```

So I am getting this exception due to not set end point url?

How to set end point url in this case ?

I have also tried to add config for endpoint in following way at starting of above method .

```
Map<String, String> sdkConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();
        sdkConfig.put("mode", "sandbox");
        sdkConfig.put("acct1.UserName", "sdk-three_api1.sdk.com");
        sdkConfig.put("acct1.Password", "QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q");
        sdkConfig.put("acct1.Signature","AVGidzoSQiGWu.lGj3z15HLczXaaAcK6imHawrjefqgclVwBe8imgCHZ");
        PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(sdkConfig);
```

but still I am getting same exception.

Please guide me in this context.

Thanks,

Comment: Any one is having idea about how to create connection with paypal using classic api/soap client?

Comment: Could you please specify where I can download `JAR` file containing following classes: `CallerServices`, `APIProfile` etc ? I can't find this JAR anywhere

Comment: From here you can download paypal_base.jar `http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpaypalbasejar.htm` . It contains all these classes.

Comment: Also do you have any idea about paypal rest sdk provides implementation methods for concurrent billing and expressCheckout? I didn't get anywhere it in paypal sdks.

Comment: I was trying to use soap , as I want to perform expressCheckout and concurrent billing .But still no luck and paypal forum is also not providing any response .Its weird.

Comment: sorry, I haven't used PayPal API via REST client, so I cannot help you here. I will download mentioned `paypal_base.jar` file and try myself tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I didn't managed to find out why `CallerService` throws mentioned exception because even after decompiling mentioned `paypal_base.jar`, the code is quite cumbersome and it's hard to find out what's going on under the hood. It looks like it's outdated or something, because I can't find reference to this JAR anywhere on the net except for several places.

But I really suggest you to stick to original documentation provided by PayPal. I tried myself and here's what I've found:

1. Follow the [Paypal API SDK and Downloads](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/) link from mentioned article, then click `Merchant` link under `Classic APIs` category (if you dig on the net, you'll find that PayPal Merchant API should be used for ExpressCheckout requests). Click `Java` button above and download SDK using either `Maven` (preferred) or simply using download link on the bottom of the page.
2. Add downloaded JAR(s) to your project and remove other PayPal JARs because downloaded `Merchant API` jar should contain all necessary classes.
3. Now everything is up to guessing :) So in your code snippet above you have formed instance of `SetExpressCheckoutRequestType` and you need `some invocation code` which takes your instance of `SetExpressCheckoutRequestType` and returns instance of `SetExpressCheckoutResponseType`.
4. I used feature `Search -> References -> Workspace` in Eclipse to find where `SetExpressCheckoutRequestType` is used in `Merchant API` jar. This search showed that (besides other places) there is class named `SetExpressCheckoutReq` which has method `setSetExpressCheckoutRequest(SetExpressCheckoutRequestType)`
5. Then I again used search feature to search for usages of `SetExpressCheckoutReq` class and found that there is class `PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService` with method `setExpressCheckout(SetExpressCheckoutReq setExpressCheckoutReq)` which returns needed `SetExpressCheckoutResponseType`.
6. Right next to `setExpressCheckout(SetExpressCheckoutReq setExpressCheckoutReq)` method, there is method which takes also `ICredential` parameter and has following signature:
   `setExpressCheckout(SetExpressCheckoutReq setExpressCheckoutReq, ICredential credential)`
7. Again using Eclipse I looked for classes that implement `ICredential` interface and found that there is class named `SignatureCredential` with constructor taking 3 parameters: username, password, signature. And this seems to me the way to go.

   So, very approximately - code snippet should now look like:

   ```
   final SetExpressCheckoutRequestType ppRequest = ...; // here you create your request as in code snippet above

   final Properties serviceConfigurationProperties = ...; // bookmark #1
   final PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(serviceConfigurationProperties);

   final SetExpressCheckoutReq request = new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
   request.setSetExpressCheckoutRequest(ppRequest);

   final ICredentials credentials = new SignatureCredentials(username, password, signature);
   final SetExpressCheckoutResponseType response = service.setExpressCheckout(request, credentials);
   ```

`Bookmark #1`: one should pass `Properties` instance with configurations of service. To find out what properties should be specified, one should google for it and try to stick to original PayPal docs rather than 3rd party blogs :) If one looks in Javadocs of  `PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService` class, he/she finds that there is file mentioned "sdk_config.properties". After googling for it, I've found several examples of that file: [Example #1](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-java/blob/master/rest-api-sample/src/main/resources/sdk_config.properties), [Example #2](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-java/blob/master/src/main/resources/sdk_config.properties)

Please note that this is not complete solution - it's rather like a collection of hints which I used before to use PayPal SOAP API. This API is changing quite often with not concise documentation, so I really suggest to download `Merchant API` jar with sourcecode and whenever some problem arises - look into code as well - this often clarifies a lot. Please also stick to original documentation of PayPal:

1. [PayPal SOAP API Basics](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/PayPalSOAPAPIArchitecture/)
2. [PayPal Merchant SDK on GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-java)

Also, in case if you don't have experience with Web Service clients in Java, I would recommend you to try to implement some simple one using tutorials on the net - this may clarify a lot.

Sorry again for not posting full and concise code snippet - I haven't worked with PayPal for 2 years from now and at that time I spent work-week to find out all the details and set it up and running. Please post questions - I will try to answer them when I have time

Hope this helps...

**EDIT**

Concerning `response.getAck()` returning `FAILURE` - I also experienced such problems in the past. I solved that by experimenting with parameters sent in the request - `PayPal` was very sensitive to those and in case if any parameter was omitted or had not correct value, simply returned `FAILURE`.

One can find full list of parameters here:
[PayPal SetExpressCheckout SOAP API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_O%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bperation_SOAP/)

Please also note, that version `2.5.106` of `Merchant SDK` uses API of version `106.0`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: thank you friend. It helped a lot. Now I am able to perform transactions using DirectPayment and also able to create recurringPaymentProfile.

Comment: But surprised, not able to execute expressCheckout , getting response.getAck()as FAILURE.

Comment: @Java I'm glad that it helped! Concerning `response.getAck()` returning `FAILURE` please refer to edited part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the endpoint url

```
    service.EndPoint=https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0
```

In addition you probably need a couple more settings:

```
    service.Binding=SOAP
    service.EndPoint=https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0
    service.RedirectURL=https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=
    service.DevCentralURL=https://developer.paypal.com
    service.IPNEndpoint=https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

If you are using the sandbox use the following settings:

```
   service.Binding=SOAP
   service.EndPoint=https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0
   service.RedirectURL=https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=
   service.DevCentralURL=https://developer.paypal.com
   service.IPNEndpoint=https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```