# Eway Payment Gateway: Add Headers using SOAP Service in Recuring payment Using Java

Tags: java, soap, runtime-error, payment-gateway, recurring-billing

I am trying to use eway payment gateway. In this i am using Recurring payment. For recurring they provide WSDL file, by using Maven Generator, i was creating java classes from WSDL file. When i was trying to call services, it generate an error, because the service need authentication information in SOAP header. From this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654608/add-soap-header-object-using-pure-jax-ws) i found the Solution to add header in SOAP request using Jaxb Object. After that, when i call the SOAP services it generates different error, which confused me. following is my code for handle eway recurring services: 
1. SOAP Handler

```
public class EwaySOAPHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>{
private JAXBElement<EWAYHeader> jaxbElement = null;

public EwaySOAPHandler(JAXBElement<EWAYHeader> jaxbElement) {
    this.jaxbElement = jaxbElement;
}

public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    Boolean outBoundProperty = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    try{
        if(outBoundProperty != null && outBoundProperty.booleanValue()){
            Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(EWAYHeader.class).createMarshaller();
            SOAPHeader header = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().addHeader();
            marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, header);
        }
        return false;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Problem In Handel Message");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not Supported Yet");
}

public void close(MessageContext context) {

}

public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
    return new TreeSet<QName>();
}
}
```

2. SOAP Client

```
public class SOAPClient {
@Test
public void test() {
    ManageRebill manageRebill = new ManageRebill();
    ManageRebillSoap manageRebillSoap = manageRebill.getManageRebillSoap();
    Binding binding = ((BindingProvider) manageRebillSoap).getBinding();
    List<Handler> handlersList = new ArrayList<Handler>();

    EWAYHeader header = new EWAYHeader();
    header.setEWAYCustomerID("87654321");
    header.setPassword("test");
    header.setUsername("test@eway.com.au");

    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
    JAXBElement<EWAYHeader> jaxbElement = factory.createEWAYHeader(header);
    EwaySOAPHandler ewaySOAPHandler = new EwaySOAPHandler(jaxbElement);

    handlersList.add(ewaySOAPHandler);
    binding.setHandlerChain(handlersList);

    manageRebillSoap.createRebillCustomer("Mr", "Pritpal", "Singh",
            "Mohali", "CHD", "Punjab", "netsol", "1610032", "india",
            "abc@abc.com", "123456789", "123456789", "987654321", "Ref123",
            "JavaEE Developer", "comments", "http://google.com");
}}
```

Following error is generate when i try to run SOAPClient test case: 
`com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/manageRebill}CreateRebillCustomerResponse but found: {http://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/manageRebill}CreateRebillCustomer`. 
According to this error, in response they need `CreateRebillCustomerResponse` but return `CreateRebillCustomer` object. the problem is that, how i change the object and where these objects are define ?.

Comment: I figure out the problem, why this exception occur, but how to resolve, still don't know. this is occur, because when i attach custom handler in my request. How i resolve this ?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I"m facing similar issues.